# Cartthrob discount settings database table

Tags: cartthrob

Can anyone point me in the right direction for finding the database table that corresponds to the information set in Cartthrob discount/coupon code settings?

I'm writing a query that needs to use the member group that's defined for a discount but trying to find this data in the database is proving a problem.

The `exp_channel_data` table has entries for discounts set up and `exp_channel_titles` all the usual data, but I fail to see any clues as to where the settings data for the related discounts reside.

We're using Cartthrob 2.70 in EE 2.10.2, any help is much appreciated!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should be able to get this from the proper `field_id_x` column in `exp_channel_data`. The column for the field is `base64_encode`d, but decoding it should get you a JSON object with the data you need!